# Learning to pasken modern Halacha questions

Tags: halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, contemporary-halacha, adult-learning, responsa

If somebody is interested, either looking to become a posek, or just interested in Halacha methodology in general, what is the best thing for them to learn if they want to understand how contemporary poskim make responsa and Halacha? By this I don’t mean just memorizing existing Halachic rulings, but the methodology behind how to make them, and by contemporary I mean ones that deal with more complex questions that arise with technological and other changes (think someone like Rabbi Moshe Feinstein or Rabbi Yisroel Belsky). How should one understand how this works

Comment: This is like asking how does one think like Stephen Hawkings. The answer is you learn a lot of math and physics. So too here, you have to learn a lot of Gemara and meforshim and poskim. There are no shortcuts.

Comment: It really does require going on some sort of course or class, and spending many years learning, with the guidance of a Rav who will guide you, test you and build you up, and provide feedback. Generally, that's what semicha courses are for, but there are all sorts of course and classes nowadays.

Comment: Just a caveat... A halachic decisor should really apprentice -- "do shimush" -- to learn from a rebbe the art and feel of pesaq. You can't get it all from books, although with a lot of examples you can get pretty far. Just pointbing out that this is a start, but it has limits. (@RabbiKaii's comment is very related.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend Mekor Chaim by Rabbi Chaim Cohen, and his blog at https://doseofhalacha.blogspot.com/, which I think includes all of the articles in Mekor Chaim.  Every article succinctly summarises the relevant opinions for a given shailah and then he gives his opinion of the final halacha.  I'm sure that's only part of the process, but I've learned a lot about how halacha is arrived at from reading these and heard other people say the same.

Comment: He's just summarizing sources. He doesn't seem to provide much in the way of determining the halacha the way Rav Moshe or Rav Belsky did.

Comment: @N.T. I think it is a good starting point for a lot of people, and he gives sources so you can look further if you want.  He also does sometimes mention sources that aren't directly answering the question, but he uses as a basis for the answer if no one has directly covered it.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to learn teshuvot.

A nice method for this is to make a map out of the teshuvot, table of contents, topics, and link them (use [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/), it makes it much fun). You probably know already which are the halachic authorities that you can "tune into". Get it from Hebrewbooks, go through the mafteach, write the topics down, tag them (similar like in Mi Yodeya).

Then choose a topic and learn, follow how he learns it. Learn through the sugya. This is much fun, even if you won't be the next Rav Moshe from it.

Here are some pictures of my own similar experience:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I would add the Arukh haShulchan to this advice, but this is close enough that I wouldn't write my own answer. The AhS gives you an insight of how the discussions of the gemara and rishonim map to accepted practice. Also, how to weigh accepted practice vs the theory you get from those and subsequent discussions.

Answer (score 0):

To understand and to learn how to pasken, start by praying about it, and ask are you fit to aspire pasken, and if so ask Hashem Yitbarakh for guidance and direction and so forth, then study the appropriate materials such as those mentioned in your question and in the other answer. In support of this is Likutei Etzot, section Prayer, #14:

> The source of the fountain of Torah wisdom emanates from prayer. Therefore, through prayer, one primarily clarifies this decisive halachic ruling, and it is considered as if he recreated the world. Through this, he succeeds in distinguishing good from evil in all four foundations, which are the rectification of everything. Through this, he merits to humble those who are proud to the ends of the earth. (L. Moharan 8:6,7)

> יד. מַעְיַן חָכְמַת הַתּוֹרָה יוֹצֵא מִתְּפִלָּה, עַל־כֵּן עִקַּר בֵּרוּר פְּסַק־הַהֲלָכָה זוֹכִין עַל־יְדֵי תְּפִלָּה, וְנֶחֱשָׁב כְּאִלּוּ חִדֵּשׁ אֶת הָעוֹלָם, וְזוֹכֶה לְבָרֵר הַטּוֹב מֵהָרָע שֶׁבְּכָל הָאַרְבָּעָה יְסוֹדוֹת שֶׁהוּא תִּקּוּן הַכֹּל, וְעַל־יְדֵי זֶה זוֹכֶה לְהַשְׁפִּיל הַחוֹלְקִים עֲדֵי אָרֶץ (ח, ו־ז)

Also Rabbi Nachman advised his followers in [Sichot haRan #76](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Sichot_Haran#76_%5BSchedule_of_Learning%5D) to follow a rigorous learning seder and to have two seders, one learning all the material quickly just saying it sufficing, all the Shas and Shulkhan Arukh and holy sefarim, and another seder learning one thing in depth, the former seder b'kius being the main seder.

I hope this helps and may you be blessed with Na Nach Nachma Nachman meUman